# I have an Issue Building the Filament Repository in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, sceneview, google-filament

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP0OU.png)

#### I'm new using Filament. I've been trying to build the repository [Google Filament](https://github.com/google/filament) but; it gives me an error every time I try to build it.

These are the errors: CMake Error at /Users/tomas/AndroidStudioProjects/06.Filament/android/gltfio-android/CMakeLists.txt:109 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:
/Users/tomas/AndroidStudioProjects/06.Filament/out/android-release/filament/include/gltfio/materials/uberarchive.h
Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
.hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc

Can someone help me to resolve this issues? I can give more information if; it's needed. [ScreenShot][1]
 
   [![ScreenShot of Android Studio][2]][2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please don't use screenshots for code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/295004). You should at least mention which [build process](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/BUILDING.md) you are following and on what platform (Linux/Windows/Mac).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [CMakeLists.txt Line 90](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/main/android/gltfio-android/CMakeLists.txt#L90) you will see that it is referring to `${FILAMENT_DIR}/include/gltfio/materials/uberarchive.h`

`$FILAMENT_DIR` itself is set to `$FILAMENT_DIST_DIR defined at Line-4

The thing is, I've been searching through the releases to find the $GLTFIO_DIR which contains that file to no avail, commenting out the line (the original Line 90) will lead to missing references for the uberarchive functions